# Python reset variable values to values in _init_

Tags: python, oop

I'm not sure if I'd be framing the question correctly but I'll try my best to explain my problem.

I have the code below where x and y are set to `None` in the beginning. In a new function, based on a condition, x and y are updated.

```
class problem()

    def __init__(self):

        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def function(self):

        if some_condition:
           self.x = 10
           self.y = 5
        else:
           self.x = None
           self.y = None
```

The problem I have here is the total number of variables in `__init__()` are around 10 and all of these have to set to a value or reset back to original value based on the condition.

Is there a pythonic way to reset the variables back to original `__init__()` values when the `if` condition fails?

Comment: Why not have a reset method that's called from both places?

Comment: make an helper function that is called by both `__init__` and `function` seems the soundest idea

Comment: maybe you could use a dictionary instead of variables. Less practical, but easier to reset.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I created a reset method and called it from __init__ and else condition. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class problem():

    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def function(self):
        if self.x == None:
            self.x = 10
            self.y = 5
        else:
            self.x = None
            self.y = None

    def reset(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

# These prints will help you understand how it works
per = problem()
per.function()
print(per.x, per.y)
per.reset()
print(per.x, per.y)
```

As easy as it looks like.
I've entered reset() into **init** because it's just looks better.
Also i'm highly recommend to check Corey Schafer's OOP Python tutorials, he
explaining in best way i've heard.